# $u(x_1,x_2) = \cosh^{-1}\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}$ is solution of$\sum_{i=1}^2D_i\left(\frac{D_iu}{\sqrt{1+|Du|^2}}\right) = 0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

> Is there any quick way to check that $u(x_1,x_2) = \cosh^{-1}\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}$ is solution of minimal surface equation 
>   $$\sum_{i=1}^2D_i\left(\frac{D_iu}{\sqrt{1+|Du|^2}}\right) = 0\ ?$$
>   Here $D_1, D_2$ are partial derivatives w.r.t. $x_1$ and $x_2$, respectively.